# Как создать систему подписки, как в tumblr или twitter?

Tags: laravel, php, sql, mysql

Я хочу сделать блог, где если я подписывался на пользователя, то его новые блоги добавлялись на моей стене.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как это сделать на голый **php** или на **laravel** и как должны выглядеть запросы к базе данных.

Comment: @POSTG, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. В текущей постановке вопрос слишком объемный для одного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Сложности реализации заключаются не в запросах, а в структуре самой БД. Могу лишь предложить идею как связать модели. Допустим есть модели User - пользователь и Post - посты. Между ними связь один ко многим (в laravel HasMany и BelongsTo),связь пользователя с его постами. Также связь User <-> User - многие ко многим (подписка). В laravel реализуется через BelongsToMany и соответственно создается промежуточная таблица со связями. В итоге для вывода постов всех пользователей, на которых вы подписаны необходимо найти этих пользователей, а затем достать их посты.