# Правильно составить запрос Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Всем привет. Я не понимаю как правильно составить запрос (eloquent) мне нужно получить новости всех пользователей,на которых я подписана.

Таблица follows: id,from_id,to_id

Таблица users: id,username,email,etc..

Таблица shots(новостей) id,user_id,title,category,etc..

Я хочу именно получить все это в один запрос,потому что в Blade,я сравниваю общее количество новостей с лимитом,который я устанавливаю - и если новостей больше,я показываю кнопку "загрузить еще",но,у меня ничего не выходит,и я,если честно,не понимаю какую именно связь мне нужно использовать. Помогите пожалуйста,или ткните в документацию на нужную связь,ее я буду копать. Спасибо

Пыталась вот так вот:

```
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Shot','App\Follow','from_id','user_id');
```

Но как я поняла eloquent не понимает что ему нужно найти посты с to_id == user_Id,а я не понимаю как ему сообщить это,мозг кипит уже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы это работало вам нужно чтобы была настроена промежуточная связь между `App\Shot` и `App\Follow`, а у вас скорее всего настроена между `App\Shot` и `App\User`.
Вообще по хорошему нужно избавиться от модели `App\Follow`, сделать связь many-to-many между `User` и `User` и тогда уже пробовать сделать

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Shot','App\User','id','user_id');
```

P.S. когда-то отвечала на похожий вопрос, мб тут понятней будет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417468/176557